# Drop Row from a Pandas Dataframe if it doesnot contain a vlaue smaller than 0.05 in at least one of the coloumns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame of 7 Rows and 100+ columns.
I want to drop the row that does not contain a value smaller than `0.05` in any of the columns. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example in idiomatic pandas:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[0.04, 0.5, 0.9], [0.12, 0.23, 0.32]])
>>> df
      0     1     2
0  0.04  0.50  0.90
1  0.12  0.23  0.32
>>>
>>> df.loc[df.le(0.05).any(axis=1)]
      0    1    2
0  0.04  0.5  0.9
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could simply construct the query chaining all the columns conditions (at least one column must be lower than 0.05) and then query the df.

Here an example:

```
query = '<0.05 | '.join(df.columns) + '<0.05'
df.query(query)
```

Comment: this didn't work my data fram has 7 row + header row and 1000 coloumns i just want the data frame to go row by row and if it dosnot find a value smaller than 0.05 it should remove the row

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood your prolem. If you have the header names inside as first row of the dataframe you can create the query using the first row `'<0.05 | '.join([str(header) for header in df.head(1).values[0]]) + '<0.05' ` and then query only the rows from 2 to 7. `df = pd.concat([df[:1], df[1:].query(query)]).reset_index(drop=True)`.